# GraphQL Argument has an invalid value. Expected type 'Int

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I'm playing around with a very basic GraphQL API in Rails.

I've got a model 'Gin' where I can return the handful of records I have in the db, however when trying to add a gin via a mutation, I'm getting an issue with the field type:

```
mutation {
  createGin(name: "Plymouth", 
description: "Gin made in Plymouth", 
abv: "40", 
url: "http://www.plymouthgin.com",) {
    id
    name
    description
    abv
    url
  }
}
```

gives the following error:

> "message": "Argument 'abv' on Field 'createGin' has an invalid value.
>   Expected type 'Int'.",

the `abv` field in the db is integer.

**gin_type.rb**

```
Types::GinType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name 'Gin'

  field :id, !types.ID
  field :name, !types.String
  field :description, !types.String
  field :abv, !types.Int
  field :url, !types.String
end
```

**create_gin.rb**

```
class Resolvers::CreateGin < GraphQL::Function

  argument :name, !types.String
  argument :description, !types.String
  argument :abv, !types.Int
  argument :url, !types.String

  type Types::GinType

  def call(_obj, args, _ctx)
    Gin.create!(
      name: args[:name],
      description: args[:description],
      abv: args[:abv],
      url: args[:ur],
    )
  end
end
```

Am I missing something elsewhere?

**UPDATE**
If I change the mutation to remove the " from around the 40, i.e. so as an integer and not a string, I get the following error message:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createGin": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Gin.url"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not a Ruby developer but, something similar happened to me in NodeJS, and to fix that i parsed the value to Integer in the resolver function, when the value is given

Comment: From the input type definition, the argument `abv` is requiring a value of type `Integer` (defined in `create_gin.rb`), but in your example of the mutation, `abv` is giving a value of type `String` (`abv: "40"`), it should be `abv: 40`

Comment: Thanks @MrYoshiji I had already tried his, but see my update in OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this mutation:

```
mutation {
  createGin(name: "Plymouth", 
description: "Gin made in Plymouth", 
abv: 40, 
url: "http://www.plymouthgin.com",) {
    id
    name
    description
    abv
    url
 }
}
```

The error message is right. You were providing the `abv` argument as a string.

**EDIT:**

In your `create_gin.rb`, you have a typo on the line

```
url: args[:ur],
```

Everytime you stumble upon an error message, first thing to assume is that it is right.

Comment: If I do this, I get a new error complaining about the url being null. I've updated the OP.